# Is it possible to do webrtc without browser?

Tags: html, node.js, webrtc

I want to do screencast my server screen using webrtc. However I want to do it without a browser. Is it possible using some node.js libraries ?

Comment: Guessing this is possible via the native API: http://www.webrtc.org/reference/native-apis

Comment: I found that it is also possible using node-webkit npm package. However there were some issues with mouse trails persisting on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webrtc is used on top of the [native api](https://webrtc.org/native-code/native-apis/). Modern browsers implement the [javascript api](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html) on top of the basis native api. Additionally there are webrtc java api's such as this [peer_connection api](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/java/src/org/webrtc). Here is a getting-started guide to build the necessary jar/so files for using the java api's:
https://webrtc.org/start

Coming back to your question: you either have to use modern browsers and take advantage of the javascript api, or implement a java/android application using the java api's. You can try to implement your own native interface that wraps the native api, which does sound scary and unnecessary to me.